# How do I precisely specify the parameters to the Bend tool?

Tags: modeling, transforms

I want to use the bend tool to bend something to a specified angle and radius, but there's no adjustments box that appears afterwards. I've tried typing while the tool is active, but this just seems to specify the angle, not the radius or clamp.

Answer (score 1):

This tool isn't as well documented as other tools, and indeed does not call a box to adjust the last operation.

The blender manual is like "yeah, it kinda works like this, just mess with it".

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/bend.html

I recommend building the initial mesh with the *Spin* tool, to gain some control over the parameters.  It basically does a segmented extrude over an arc.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/spin.html

Comment: I've read that, and I want to specify an *exact numeric value* for the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Simple Deform modifier instead.
It gives way better control, and let's you input precise angles.

1. Add *Simple Deform* modifier
2. Set it to *Bend*
3. Specify an axis/angle...

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, that one doesn't seem to allow me to specify that only a part of the object should be curved (i.e. to make a bend between straight segments, controlled by the "Radius" property, which is what I'm seeking to control precisely.).